# NSCocoaErrorDomain error 516 caused by bringing PNG into Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, copy

I am trying to import PNG images into Xcode (version 4.6.2) on my Mac. These images were created on a Windows 7 machines, and stored on a NAS box.

In finder, when I drag the images from my NAS box into Xcode I get the following error:

> The operation couldn't be completed. (NSCocoaErrorDomain error 516).

Using Get Info on that file, Sharing & Permissions only states that `You have custom access`.

Ive managed to copy these images onto a folder on my Mac's desktop. Using Get Info on these local images, Sharing & Permissions that My User, Staff and Everybody all have Read & Write permissions. I can make copies of these images on my Mac and I can edit these images on my Mac.

When I try and drag these local images into Xcode, I still get the same `NSCocoaErrorDomain 516`.

---

EDIT:

Because I read somewhere that the extended attributes could be causing this error, I have just used a Terminal Window to copy the files using this command:

```
cp -X button.png button2.png
```

But again, this gives me the same `NSCocoaErrorDomain 516`.

---

EDIT 2:

This is getting really infuriating now. If I rename the files, the Xcode accepts the files with no problem. If I rename the file back to what it was, Xcode kicks out the `NSCocoaErrorDomain 516` error again. I could go and rename the hundreds of images and change the references to them in my code, but I would really rather find out the cause of this problem.

---

Ive been making the images on a Windows machine and importing them into Xcode fine for the last two weeks without problem. Today I do the same thing and suddenly this problem occurs. Nothing has changed to the Windows machine or the NAS box. My Mac has not been updated, nor am I aware of any changes to my Mac.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get these images into Xcode?

Comment: Are you getting this error in Xcode, or in your app?

Answer (score 3):

From [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

> NSFileWriteFileExistsError = 516

I think You have folder/file named button.png

Comment: I have a file named "button.png" but no folder named "button.png" or even just "button".